# Angular 2 webpack application taking lot of time to load in IE due to some ".js.map" files

Tags: angular, webpack

[image]Whenever i am trying to open my angular 2 webpack application in the IE11, it is taking more load time than chrome browser. When i checked in the Network tab, it seems that IE is trying get a lot of files with prefix ".js.map" like /Observable.js.map, /root.js.map, /toSubscriber.js.map// etc. and it is not able to find it and hence returning status 404. I don't know from where these files are coming since i don't see this in Chrome browser. Please help.

Comment: have you considered an AOT build for prod with bundling and minification?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you are still in the developer mode. Once you run 
ng build --prod
it will build your app for production and completely optimize it. The only other thing that could be causing this issue would be a slow internet/computer speed.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the .map files from you compilation build. Make sourcemap in tsconfig as false. If you are not using ng-cli, I strongly recommend you to use it to manage your projects, build, and deployment.

`"sourceMap": false,`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```